# FileInfo constructor reporting long filenames when they're shorter than 256 chars

Tags: c#, .net, file, filesystems

I'm being passed a filename, and I need to verify whether it's valid.

There are many criteria a valid filename must meet in order to be considered valid in Windows, one of which is that [its length cannot exceed 256 characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#maxpath).

In order to validate this property (and many others), I'm leveraging the `FileInfo` constructor:

```
try
{
    var fi = new FileInfo(filename);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //PathTooLongException among others
}
```

However, a `PathTooLongException` is being thrown even for filenames under 256 characters (e.g. 240 chars). Why is that?

Note that:

- the file itself does not have to exist
- the filename I'm given will *not* contain any path segments (e.g. `C:/filename.txt` or `//filename.txt`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string being passed into the `FileInfo` constructor is a simple filename with no path segments (e.g. `filename.txt`), then it will be prefixed with the current working directory.

So if you're application is running under `C:/Really/Long/I/Mean/Reaaaally/Long/Path`, then `filename.txt` will be transformed into `C:/Really/Long/I/Mean/Reaaaally/Long/Path/filename.txt`.

So, even though `filename.txt` is a perfectly valid and short filename, it may become invalid after being prefixed.

To avoid this, prefix it with `C:/` instead:

```
try
{
    var fi = new FileInfo("C:/" + filename);
}
```